# How to find the the guitar notes in the staff notation if it starts from other than key of C

Tags: notation, strings, classical-guitar

I can identify the open string in the key of C, but i don't know how to identify the open string if it starts from other than key of C,Can someone help me, I have shown below the music sheets[image]

Where is the guitar notes in which fret it falls if it starts from key of Bb?

Open string in the key of C, is shown below
[image]

How to indentify open strings in the staff notation?

Comment: What do you mean "the open string"? Can you explain what and where "the open string" is in C?

Comment: I have shown in my post for open string in C @piiperi

Comment: This question isn't easy to follow. Could you please ask it another way? The open strings are the same note names whatever key a piece is in. Those open notes are not really 'in C', they just happen to all be notes from the key of C. Or key G, or key D or key A

Comment: I am sorry for my way of asking question, this makes you all confussion. I have modified my question @Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look at the notes in the scale. Whichever of them happens to be E, A, D, G or B, (or an enharmonic equivalent) can potentially be played with an open string, at least from the one octave. And assuming that your guitar is tuned to regular E A D G B E tuning.

The C major scale doesn't have any sharps or flats, and its notes are:

- C, D, E, F, G, A, B

From this set of notes, D, E, G, A and B can be played using an open string (in the one octave where the open strings are). For C and F, no open string can be found.

Bb major has two flats: Bb and Eb. The notes of the scale are:

- Bb, C, D, Eb, F, G, A, Bb

From this set of notes, D, G and A can be played using an open string, at least in one octave. For Bb, C, Eb and F, no open string can be found.

[image: Guitar open strings on Bb scale]

The E, B and E strings are nowhere on the Bb major scale, so that's why there's no arrows for them.

The higher A note on the staff doesn't have an arrow pointing to any string. That's because it's in a higher *octave* than the open A string.

(Enharmonic equivalent means, for example Fb - if you ever encounter such a thing - can be played with the E string. Cb can be played with the B string.)

Comment: This could end up sounding rather strange. OP is obviously a beginner, and could well play those open strings in another octave to the dots! Could be fun!

Comment: @Tim Well yeah, I noticed that when making the picture ... maybe it isn't obious without specifically pointing out that the higher A doesn't have an arrow even though there's an A string. :)